# Basic Clarification on S-Polynomials & Buchberger's Criterion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

I am trying to work through the text Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms and I came across this lemma in the section discussing S-Polynomials & Buchberger's Criterion.

It is stated:

Suppose we have a sum $\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$, where $c_i \in k$ and multideg($f_i)$ = $\delta \in Z^{n}$ $|$ $n \geq 0$ for all i. If multideg ($\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$) < $\delta, $ then $\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$ is a linear combination, with coefficients in K, of the S-polynomials $S(f_j,\,f_k) \; \text{for} \;1 \leq j,k \leq s$. Furthermore each $S(f_i,\:f_k)$ has multidegree $< \delta$.

In particular my specific questions are:

1) When it says "multideg($f_i)$ = $\delta \in Z^{n}$ $|$ $n \geq 0$ for all i" does this mean every $f_i$ in the ideal has the same multideg? or does it mean multideg$(f_i) = \delta_i$.  If it is the former, why does every polynomial have to have the same multideg?

2) "If multideg ($\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$) < $\delta$".  Related to question 1, what does this $\delta$ refer to?

Comment: I don't have the book with me, but I don't think there are any typos. 1. It means each one of (only) f_1 to f_s has multidegree $\delta$, not that every ideal in the polynomial hast he same degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the book with me, but I don't think there are any typos. 1. It means each  of (only) f_1 to f_s has multidegree $\delta$, not that every polynomial in the ideal has  the same degree (only every polynomial in the list). Why? Because we want to say that in the sum $\Sigma c_if_i$ Has smaller degree because we are saying Some cancellation occurs and that's how we end up with something of a different degree. Look at a concrete example involving the s-polynomial and you will see what I mean.

2. $\delta$ refers to the common degree of the $f_i$

Comment: Got it! That makes a lot more sense.  Thanks